# Ayuda Merge Git

Tags: git, github

Empecé a desarrollar parte de un código y un compañero de trabajo subió otra parte a GitHub. Lo descargué pero ahora le quiero hacer merge pero local (en mi pc, sin subirlo aun a github)

Es posible hacerlo? Como lo hago?

PD: es en Java en el ide Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Si, claro... para eso está hecho git.

Haz un `git fetch` (indicando el remote... `origin` probablemente?) Y luego haces un merge de la rama remota en tu rama local:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/rama-de-mi-amigo -m "Mezclando lo de mi amigo"
```

Coloca un comentario apropiado. Si solo quieres probar el merge puedes correr el merge con `--no-commit` para luego hacer un reset y volver a tu estado inicial.